# How can I combine jQuery and PHP to dynamically change input values based on user choices?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

So basically this is what I want to do:

I have a php variable called `$dynamicchange` which gets a different value based on different user selections (which page they're on etc.)

I also have a few select option form inputs which have 'All' as an entry in them.

With jQuery, I want to do this:

```
 [every 1 millisecond, check for and update all input fields if needed] << function

if ($dynamicchange == 'en') {
do not replace anything, the phrase stays as it is, 'All'.
}
if ($dynamicchange == 'tr') {
replace all input phrases every 1 millisecond, changing them to 'Hepsi'.
}
```

A sample input option I want to target is:

```
 <select id="sub_cat" style="" name="sub_cat">
 <option selected="selected" value="-10">All</option>
```

if the value of `$dynamicchange` is `en`, it stays as it is and if it's `tr`, it changes to `Hepsi`.

How do I go about doing this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you want exactly, but from what I've understood you could do something like this

Put the value in a hidden input

```
<input id="test" hidden="hidden" value="$dynamicchange">
```

then do something like this

```
$(function(){
   var herp = $('#test').val();
   if(herp=="en"){
        //do stuff
    }else{ 
        //do other stuff
    }
});
```

You can have a counter (not 1 ms your pc will explode) where it triggers again the function. You don't make clear how this function will fire in the first place so I leave that to your judgement(I would do window.load())

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to the server that often cannot be healthy.

You could use ajax-jquery in this case as shown below:

```
$.get('phpfile', { send your data }, function(returned) { if returned == en ... } );
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly I think you should use AJAX scripting and introduce events for the "choices" the visitor makes. You need to have separate PHP page with the text and elements that you want to display.
Your Javascript should look like this:

```
function showText(cv){//cv is an element identifier which is posted to php page
var url='show.php';
$.post(url,{contentVar:cv}, function (data){
$('#textt').html(data).show();
});
}
function eraseText (){
document.getElementById('textt').innerHTML="What you want it to say by default";
}
```

In the HTML document you have to have elements with IDs that the Javascript will be able to recognize, something like:

```
<p onmouseover="JavaScript:showText('id1');" onmouseout="JavaScript:eraseText();">Some 
text</p><!--this is the element upon which the actions taken will change the page, you
can have many such elements but you need to change the id inside ('id1')-->
<div id="textt"style="position: fixed; bottom: 20%; left: 20%; background: lightgrey; 
width: 70%; height: 70%;">What you want it to say by default
<br /></div><!--this is the element that will be changed upon action, you can define 
more such elements by adding more rows in the function-->
```

Finaly your show.php document should look like this:

```
<?php
$contentVar=$_POST['contentVar'];
if ($contentVar=='id1') {
echo 'Text that you want to be displayed instead';}
//you can use multiple 'else if' loops afterwards
?>
```

Hope that helps.